# Availability Group Listener Loses Connectivity on Failover

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, listener, basic-availability-groups

I have 2 SQL server 2016 standard Servers.

1. Production (SRV1).
2. For reporting (SRV2)

Both servers are nodes in WSFC.

SRV1 replicates the production database (DB1) to SRV2 with the distributor being on SRV2 (this is for reporting purposes since secondary replicas aren't readable in SQL 2016 Standard).

I have following availability groups in-place:

1. **AG_DIST**

   - SRV2 is primary replica, SRV1 is secondary replica
   - Hosts **DB2**  (the distribution database)
   - Listener name: `Dist_lsnr`.
   - This AG ensures that the distribution database is always available.
2. **AG_PROD**

   - SRV1 is primary replica, SRV2 is secondary replica
   - Hosts **DB1** (Production database)
   - Listener name: `PROD_lsnr`

All is well when I fail-over WSFC or fail `AG_DIST` to `SRV1`. The problem arises when failing over `AG_PROD` to `SRV2`.

When this is done the application connections using `PROD_lsnr` lose connectivity with the PROD database.

When I fail the AG back the applications can again connect to the database.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Do you mean, the replication configured with production database (for reporting purpose) while the db part of Availability Group ?

Comment: Is this a multi-subnet WSFC?  If so, what is the client driver?  Does the AGL come online after the failover?  And are you setting MultiSubnetFailover on the client?

Comment: For Shekar - The production database on SRV1 is replicated to SRV2 for reporting. The reason for this is that the AG replica of production on SRV2 is not readable. This is a restriction imposed when using SQL 2016 Standard

Comment: For David Browne - Define multi-subnet WSFC. The AG groups come online as expected.